# Doing sensor fusion in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sensors, sensor-fusion

So, the Android JAVA SDK has provisions to do sensor fusion.
It can combine gyro and accelerometer readings to generate a reliable gravity vector.
This is exposed in the API with the sensor type [TYPE_GRAVITY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_GRAVITY).

Now, the NDK has sensor support as well, for instance, here is an example NDK app that reads the accelerometer at 60Hz: [NativeActivity sample source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html)

However, judging from the [sensor.h sourcecode](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/include/gui/Sensor.h), the NDK only lets me generate the following sensor types:

- Accelerometer
- Magnetic field
- Gyroscope
- Light
- Proximity

So the sample code uses ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER. Sadly, there is no ASENSOR_TYPE_GRAVITY. Is this simply a case of NDK only doing a barebones subset of the SDK API?

How can I do sensor fusion on Android NDK? I would like to avoid bringing in the values from Java, as I have read warnings on heavy CPU use when doing high frequency readings in Java.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for this, but I've had the same problem recently and just thought that I would share how I solved this.

ASENSOR_TYPE_*'s are defined as int so replacing ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEORMETER with 1 would still give you access to the accelerometer sensor to use other sensors take a look at

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html

and find the int value for the sensor you want use and use that in place of ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER. For example to use the GYROSCOPE you could use 4.

or you could define your own set of int too using #define